# get value from telerik combobox clientside

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

I have added a rad combobox to a page and need to be able to get the selected value from it. I can see below the html element a hidden field called 'mycontrol_ClientState' I take it this is where I am meant to retrieve the value from however I dont know how to.

Does anyone have an example of getting the value out clientside?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `get_value()` JavaScript method:

```
var combobox = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
var value = combobox.get_value();
```

Comment: Thanks Atanas. I wasnt using $find